# What happens if I submit two CloudFormation change sets almost at the same time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

If I submit two change sets one right after the other, is the first guaranteed to complete before the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what you mean by submitting a changeset. If you're talking about creating changesets, then this shouldn't be a problem, since it won't actually execute anything on your stack.

If you're talking about executing a changeset on a stack, CloudFormation will probably not accept the second changeset you have submitted since you cannot update a stack that has an in-progress status.

After the first changeset is executed successfully, the second changeset will automatically be removed as it is no longer valid for the stack after the update has been applied. Hence, if you try to use the ID of the old changeset, you will get a `ChangeSetNotFound` error.

What I'm sure won't happen, is CloudFormation will execute both changesets sequentially.